# InstallEventLoopTimer timer gets stopped when NSApp runModalForWindow is called

Tags: cocoa, timer

I'm using InstallEventLoopTimer to create a timer, that needs to run several times per second during the whole time the software is running. However when I then use NSApp runModalForWindow, the timer is stopped until the window is closed. How to avoid this?

Btw. I need to use Carbon too, so InstallEventLoopTimer instead of NSTimer is correct.

Comment: I expect that an `NSTimer` would work even in a Carbon window or event loop.  By the way there is a 3rd option, `CFRunLoopTimerCreate`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by simply creating the exact same timer right before entering runModalForWindow. But can someone explain to me why this works?? It makes no sense, the timer is the same, just created later.